# Requesting migrations from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm a moderator on Stack Overflow, and I've recently noticed quite a few flags asking for questions that might be a better fit on Drupal SE to be migrated. While we generally *agree* with most of the flags, there's a few things that have to be taken into consideration:

- We can't migrate a question that is *technically* on topic for Stack Overflow without the original author requesting it.
- Drupal SE is not in our normal migration path, so we really do need a compelling reason to migrate (the OP asking would be quite compelling)
- Your flags tend to stick around in our moderation queue for a week or more, because while we agree, many moderators aren't quite sure what action to take.

In the future, please do the following:

1. Leave a comment letting the author know about Drupal SE and that they will probably get better answers much faster here. Suggest that they flag their own question for migration.
2. As needed, explain a bit how flagging works.

This helps us to help our users by sending them somewhere more appropriate, while helping you to get the questions on SO that you want. Keep in mind, however that someone might have chosen Stack Overflow strategically - perhaps they simply don't want to ask on another network site.

As long as the request for the migration comes from the OP, we'll have no problem sending the question on its way to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what said, but I think that leaving a comment to the OP to let them know questions for Drupal can be asked on Drupal Answers has, in most of the cases, the effect of having the same exact question asked in two different SE sites.

Drupal Answers is still in beta, but when it goes off beta phase, questions about Drupal on Stack Overflow don't become off-topic. This is the same case of questions about Apple products that can still be asked on Super User.
Probably, the community on Stack Overflow should decide if there are Drupal questions that are not particularly liked on *Stack Overflow*, and mark them for migration on *Drupal Answers*. I can imagine that questions about the theme to use, or which module to use, asked from the point of view of somebody that doesn't create Drupal modules are not particularly about developing.

I would also add that if the OP is asking most of his questions on *Stack Overflow*, but few of them are about Drupal, then I can see a reason for him to keep asking his questions on Stack Overflow, even though I would like if there would be some questions destined to *Drupal Answers*.